# lwgeom_to_geojson: 'PolyhedralSurface' geometry type not supported

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson, sfcgal

I am using PostGIS (PostGIS 2.2.0 with SFCGAL extension) and I have data in postgres which is loaded using citygml2psql tool and it contains polyhedralSurface geometry.

But when i run query :

```
SELECT "gid",ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform("geom"::geometry,3946),0, 1) AS "geom"  FROM "public"."citygml"
```

in pgadmin3 it gives an error  :

```
ERROR:  lwgeom_to_geojson: 'PolyhedralSurface' geometry type not supported
********** Error **********
ERROR: lwgeom_to_geojson: 'PolyhedralSurface' geometry type not supported
SQL state: XX000
```

I found one question related to this here : [GeoJSON: PolyhedralSurface geometry type not supported](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166748/geojson-polyhedralsurface-geometry-type-not-supported)

But i want some fix for postgis as I can't change my query and need data in GeoJSON.

Comment: What OS, did you build from source, etc, etc. More details please.

Answer (score 2):

The error message and [specifications](http://geojson.org/) are pretty clear:

> GeoJSON supports the following geometry types: `Point`, `LineString`, `Polygon`, `MultiPoint`, `MultiLineString`, and `MultiPolygon`.

`PolyhedralSurface` is not in that list, so you'll need to convert it to another geometry type.

Comment: How can i convert PolyhedralSurface geometry into polygon or MultiPolygon  for my above query.

Comment: There is no equivalent GeoJSON geometry type, which is why the conversion is not supported! Try using ST_Dump and/or ST_GeometryN to extract part(s) to [Multi]Polygons, which can be converted to GeoJSON.

Answer (score -1):

If anybody came across this error please read [this](https://github.com/Oslandia/cesium-buildings/issues/5). I was able to solve this using this info.

Comment: Link is dead and gone, you really should have posted the info here so it was kept alive :}